# How to perform SUM() function within a Common Table Expression (CTE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have given it multiple goes, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is this possible? Below is what is my current attempt:

```
With PrintsPerDayPerEmp(ID,[Month],[Day],[Year], [Number Of Prints])
AS
(Select ID,
    datepart(month,Agent_Local_Time) as [Month],
    datepart(day,Agent_Local_Time) as [Day],
    datepart(year,Agent_Local_Time) as [Year],
    count(RowID) as [Number of Prints]
From Table1
Where Agent_Local_Time >= (getdate()-90)
Group by datepart(day,Agent_Local_Time),
    datepart(month,Agent_Local_Time),
    datepart(year,Agent_Local_Time),
    ID
)
select *
from PrintsPerDayPerEmp
where [Number Of Prints] > (sum([Number Of Prints])/90)*3
order by ID desc
```

Comment: So show us your `goes` , what exactly do you expect us to do?

Comment: Sorry :) Added it.

Comment: I guess this logic here would obviously give me sum of entire column as one number, but I'd like it to show the sum for each ID found....if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't seem to be working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'Print Sum'. I'm not sure where the syntax error is either. If I comment out those sections it works fine and returns the month, day, year, ID, and print count per day of each ID found within the past 90 days.

Comment: You have to explain with sample data and outcome what you want to get, because the query makes no sense: `sum(count(RowID))` is invalid, you'll get an error like *"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate"*. Also a `group by` clause should not have an aggregate function in it.

Comment: I'm getting this error now -- _Column 'Table1.RowID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause._

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server due to the `getdate()` function.

I'm not sure why you're trying to use a CTE.  It appears to be completely unnecessary.

My guess is that you're expecting sum(count(RowID)) to be the overall total, but that's not how aggregate functions work.  The GROUP BY clause effects all aggregate functions.

My guess is that this is what you want.  It uses the OVER() clause to control aggregation and get an overall total:

```
Select Id,
    datepart(month,Agent_Local_Time) as 'Month',
    datepart(day,Agent_Local_Time) as 'Day',
    datepart(year,Agent_Local_Time) as 'Year',
    count(RowID) as 'Number Of Prints',
    count(RowID) over () as 'Print Sum'
From Table1
Where Agent_Local_Time >= (getdate()-90)
Group by datepart(day,Agent_Local_Time),
    datepart(month,Agent_Local_Time),
    datepart(year,Agent_Local_Time),
    Id
Order by Id desc
```

Or this:

```
Select Id,
    datepart(month,Agent_Local_Time) as 'Month',
    datepart(day,Agent_Local_Time) as 'Day',
    datepart(year,Agent_Local_Time) as 'Year',
    count(RowID) as 'Number Of Prints',
    count(RowID) over (partition by Id) as 'Print Sum'
From Table1
Where Agent_Local_Time >= (getdate()-90)
Group by datepart(day,Agent_Local_Time),
    datepart(month,Agent_Local_Time),
    datepart(year,Agent_Local_Time),
    Id
Order by Id desc
```

But without some data and expected results it's very difficult to tell.

Comment: Thanks to everyone trying to help - it's been a long weekend with holiday, so I haven't been able to respond/work on this as much. But basically, the result I'm trying to find is the following:

1. Returns every ID and their daily print count where their daily print count > than 3x that ID's print avg for the last 90 days.

Right now, my query is returning every ID, month/day/year, and print count of every ID found within the last 90 days...The problem is I can't seem to get the 90 day avg to see if for a given day, their print count is 3x more than that  avg.

Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  In SQL Server, the correct escape character is double quotes or square braces.

Second, the `group by` is all wrong.

I think this is basically the query you want, assuming that `id` is the employee id:

```
With PrintsPerDayPerEmp([Id],[Month],[Day],[Year], [Number Of Prints], [Print Sum])
AS (
      Select Id, datepart(month, Agent_Local_Time) as [Month],
             datepart(day, Agent_Local_Time) as [Day],
             datepart(year, Agent_Local_Time) as [Year],
             count(RowID) as [Number of time per Day],
             sum(count(RowID)) over () as [Print Sum]
      From Table1
      Where Agent_Local_Time >= (getdate() - 90)
      Group by datepart(day, Agent_Local_Time),
               datepart(month, Agent_Local_Time),
               datepart(year, Agent_Local_Time),
               Id
     )
select *
from PrintsPerDayPerEmp 
order by Id desc;
```

Comment: My newest attempt has been edited into the original posting of code.

Comment: @RoflWaffle17 . . . You have changed the logic of the query.  You cannot use aggregation functions in a `where` clause.  Remove the `where` and the question is answered.  If you have another need, then ask another question.